# Best manual settings for Canon 60D

Tags: canon, camera-settings, manual-mode, fashion, blog

I am a novice fashion photographer and have been attempting to master the art of shooting in manual mode. I have a Canon 60D and was hoping to get some tips on setting the aperture, shutter speed, ISO, exposure meter, etc. to achieve a professional looking image that shows a clear subject with a bokeh background.

I've been advised as a beginner to master the art of shooting in manual mode before attempting the other settings. What I'm trying to accomplish is shooting a fashion blogger with the desired bokeh background. I have been having difficulty capturing my subject (the fashion blogger) without making her appear overexposed or grainy while maintaining the bokeh effect. I am looking for the winning formula from professional photographers who have experience shooting fashion bloggers.

Comment: By "attempting to master the art of shooting in manual mode", it sounds like you don't have a problem with the concepts of exposure controls and their tradeoffs. If so, then what exactly are you asking about? As written, this question is too broad. From the [help/dont-ask]'s _What types of questions should I avoid asking_ page: "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." General "gimme tips" questions aren't suited to the Stack Exchange format. Give us examples of what you are trying to do, what you've tried, and why you feel it is lacking. =)

Comment: Why do you think you have to use manual mode?

Comment: I've been told that beginners should master the art of shooting in manual mode before attempting other settings. What I'm trying to accomplish is shooting a fashion blogger with the desired bokeh background. I have been having difficulty achieving clarity with my subject (the fashion blogger) that doesn't end up looking overexposed or grainy.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, but there are no "best settings" - if there were, then the camera wouldn't have other ones. You need to understand the [exposure triangle](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle) and know the compromises you make when you change any of them.

Comment: Are you saying that in order to achieve my desired effect, I have to adjust the exposure triangle to find my own formula? Doesn't it also depend on the lens?

Comment: I think Philip is trying to say that *yes*, as strange as it seems, you need to learn photography. The exposure triangle is the base of it, especially in manual mode.